# Calculate or reduce Button press Delay aka Input lag

Tags: league-of-legends

As a Tryndamere main I have a problem. The ultimate is supposed to be instant and always able to be cast, but there are times where I'm 100% sure that I pressed the "ultimate key" before dying a couple ms later.

- I have a 120hz Monitor with GSync (but only get around 100 fps in
  average)
- I play with around 50ms ping
- I play with the Keyboard: HyperX Alloy Elite RGB w. Cherry Reds

My question is, is there a way to calculate how long it takes for the key input to register on Windows till when the game actually gets the input?

Like an Tool that is Listening on Key-Events from Windows and League of Legends itself. If not is there maybe anything else?

And are there settings which can help to reduce your input lag.

Comment: Any tool that does this will simply make the problem worse.  I don't see how you can win in this situation other than pressing it just slightly sooner.  If you can tell the time difference of couple ms, then just do it couple ms earlier.

Comment: I would use it only to test a couple times. All i need is that it can detect raised Events (or something like that) from the Game, then i could just write a Program which calculates the difference between the Windows and Game Event. I dont know if that would delay inputs, but i wouldnt imagine so.

Comment: Not sure how LoL actually reacts to input, but I think it was on button pressed. Therefore the button registers in the game immediately (like really immediately). The game then needs to send the input to the server which takes roughly half your ping, so 25ms. I doubt its known how the server handles input that happens at the exact same time (from you and enemy), but you could simply be unlucky in that regard (enemy deals damage before you cast your ult). I am not quite sure, but I think there was an option ingame to reduce input lag, but I would need to check.

Comment: Any tool to calculate the delay would need to be integrated in both the host system as well as the game and since LoL doesn't have a tool like that, you would need to hack the client which is against ToS

Answer (score 3):

Would be pretty sure that its not a monitor response problem, its a ping or you pressed it too late problem.

Even if you pressed the ult button, you are not actually ulting until the server receives the signal that you pressed the R key; if in the eye of the server you died before you ulted, you died. The server is absolute.

Ping is calculated in the time it takes for a packet (a small amount of data) takes to go to the server and then come back (in milliseconds). So if your ping is 200 (a pretty bad ping yes) it would take about 0.1s (3 frames) between you pressing R and actually being in ult in the eye of the server.

There's a checkbox in the options to show your current ping, I just don't remember what is the name.

But your ping is only 50, so I would guess that you should just try to take a habit to activate a little earlier. In LoL you can be bursted down pretty quick, so maybe you feel like it was on time, but it was too late.

Comment: I agree with the last line. It is so easy to think you have more time than you actually have. Tryndamere is pretty squishy, so someone else with high critical chance or lethality can kill you must faster than you expected. A key part of Tryndamere is being able to predict when you need to smash that R button.